Need help sorting the output of a powershell function by folder/file size
(Sorry if the title isn't the best, I had no idea how to write what I meant)
Hello, I'm somewhat new to PowerShell but I wanted to create a function that I could run whenever I wanted to see the sizes of every Folder in the current directory.
I found the following code which looked exactly like what I needed.. however, no matter where I place the Sort-Object it won't sort anything. I'm sure it's user error since I've never really used Sort-Object before and since I haven't found much online I decided to just ask instead.

function Print-Sizes {
    $colItems = Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}
    foreach ($i in $colItems)
    {
    $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
    '{0:N2}' -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + ' MB' + '     |   ' + $i.Name
    }
}


This is placed on the Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 file.
As I've somewhat mentioned, I've tried adding Sort-Items -Property Length but no matter where I insert it, it never sorts what Powershell prints.
Am looking to know what I did / am doing wrong.
Thank you in advance!

Did you define $startFolder anywhere?? And, since you do Select-Object Sum, the items in $subFolderItems will be objects with only one property named Sum

For a lot of files, it's faster using .net instead of get-childitem, like Jeff Hicks's Get-FolderSizeInfo script.

@Theo No but it works for the current directory I'm in, which is my goal so I decided it was fine. Should I change it?

@js2010 I see. Might look into it. I wanted to do it with PowerShell only but I can check that out. Thanks!

It's still powershell.

Since the foreach loop in your code outputs formatted strings, there are no objects with a property Length to sort on anymore.
Assuming your variable $startFolder is defined somewhere before you call the function, I would change it into something like below
function Print-Sizes {
    $colItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $startFolder -Directory
    # loop over the subfolders and collect objects with properties Size and Name
    $result = foreach ($folder in $colItems) {
        $size = (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName -Recurse -Force -File | 
                 Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
        # output a custom object for each subfolder
        [PsCustomObject]@{ 
            Size = [Math]::Round($size / 1MB, 2)  # store numerical [double] values, not formatted strings
            Name = $folder.Name 
        }
    } 
    # sort on Size property
    $result | Sort-Object -Property Size
}

The output will look like
   Size Name                                     
   ---- ----                                     
  44,83 Folder1                               
 125,99 Folder2   
 277,82 Folder3           
 841,24 Folder Etcetera          
5520,33 PowerShell  

P.S. my system is Dutch, so the decimal point here is a comma

Actually, strings have a Length property.

Thank you! That worked wonderfully. However, I have two questions.. Is it possible to reverse the order so it descends instead of ascending? And is there a proper way to make it print " MB" after each number? (just to tidy it up a little, if not then it's alright)

@Evellyn You can simply append -Descending to the Sort-Object line to reverse the sorting. As for the MB in the output. Because you want to sort on numeric values (not strings), it is best to keep the sizes in the $result array as double values as they are now. You could of course rename the property Size to SizeMB or something, but then also make sure you change that name is the Sort-Object command aswell.

# function with approved verb but using alias for your preferred non-approved-verb name
Function Show-DirectorySize {
    [Alias('Print-Size')]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, Mandatory)]
        [validatenotnullorempty()]
        [string]$startFolder,

        # sometimes one might need to see things from the opposite side
        # Best Practice would probably want the sorting being delegated to piping the unsorted output, but this is a Personal Utility function, so who cares?
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [Alias('Reverse')]
        [switch]$Descending,

        # for when one might need the size value in numeric, not a string
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [switch]$Raw
    )

    process {
        Get-ChildItem $startFolder -Directory -PipelineVariable SubDir | 
            ForEach-Object {
                if ($SubDirMeasure = Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse -Force -File | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum) {
                    $SubDirMeasure | Select-Object @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = { $SubDir.Name } }, @{Name = 'Size'; Expression = { if ($Raw) { $_.Sum } else { '{0:n2} MB' -f ($_.Sum / 1MB) } } }
                }
                # if the directory+sub has NO files, returns a 0 without decimals
                # this helps to differentiate on-look empty directories from those with small files complessively weighting less than 10kB
                else {
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Name = $SubDir.Name
                        Size = if($Raw) {0 } else{ '0 MB'}
                    }
                } 
            } | Sort-Object -Property Size, Name -Descending:$Descending
    }

}    

PS > Print-Size -StartFolder $Path
Name                Size
----                ----
Empty_dir_1         0 MB
Empty_Dir_2         0 MB
DirWithSubKBfiles1  0,00 MB
DirWithSubKBfiles2  0,00 MB
Dir_of_some_size    10,67 MB


That looks exactly like what I want, however... when placed inside the profile.ps1 powershell throws a bunch of errors.
> Pastebin

That is because PowerShell versions below 7.x do not have the ternary operator..

@Evellyn Fixed it to be compatible with 5.1; My fault I forgot to ask what version were you using it.
